# Prove that there exist sets $A, B, C$ with $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$ and $A \not \subseteq B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that there exist sets $A, B, C$ with $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup  C$ and $A \not \subseteq B$

Here is my attempt:

Proof: Suppose $x \in A \cup C$. Then by definition we know that $in  \in A$ or $x \in C$. Also suppose that $x \in B \cup C$. Then by definition we know that $x \in B$ or $x \in C$.

Now at this point how can I say that$ A \not \subseteq B$? How can I build on my assumptions?

### **Update:**

Thanks to @mfl and @egreg: Since in the question it says **"Prove that there exist"**, then all I would need is just show **ONE** *case* where the proposition holds!

> Proof: Let $A$ = {1}, $B$ = {2}, and $C$ = {1,3}.
>
> $A$ $\cup$ $C$ = {1,3}
>
> $B$ $\cup$ $C$ = {1,2,3}
>
> It is clear that $A$ $\not\subseteq$ $B$ but $A$ $\cup$ $C$ $\subseteq$ $B$ $\cup$ $C$

***is that enough?***

Comment: You are supposed to give an example of sets rather than giving a proof.

Comment: You are right. "Prove that there exist sets ..." in this question is equivalent to "Find three sets ...".

Comment: @lucidgold your answer doesn't work but only because you claim that $\{1,3\} \subseteq \{2,3\}$ which is not true

Comment: @Gage: Oops, how about now?

Comment: Your example works now.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that B$\subset$C and A$\subset$C.  Then (A∪C)⊆(B∪C), since (A∪C)=C=(B∪C).  Now you need to find another set such that B$\subset$A.

So to construct an example, let C have three elements.  Pick two of those elements to belong to A.  And then pick one of the elements of A to belong to B.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take your favorite sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A\not\subseteq B$ and choose $C=A\cup B$.

Note that you can't prove in general that $A\not\subseteq B$ from $A\cup C\subseteq B\cup C$, because it doesn't necessarily hold.

Answer (score 0):

Just let
$A \subseteq C$
.

Then
$A \cup C \subseteq B \cup  C$
for any $B$.

Then choose $B$ appropriately.